# My Visual Studio code app keeps deleting my imported package

Tags: go, types, package

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    type (
        fullGram int

        fullKilogram int

        fullTon int
    )


var (
    salt fullGram = 100

    apples fullKilogram = 5

    truck fullTon = 10
)

fmt.Printf("salt: %d, apples: %d, truck: %d\n", salt, apples, truck)

salt = fullGram(weights.callGram(100))

fmt.Printf("Type of weights.Gram: %T\n", weights.callGram(1))


}


package weight

type (

        callGram int

       callKilogram int

       callTon int
)
```

I am working on a simple code program that is supposed to call a type from another custom file. 
The problem I have with it is that whenever I try to import the path `/Users/inanc/go/src/github.com/inancgumus/learngo/weights` my app will instantly delete the import upon my attempt to save the file.

And because of this, I can never call the file properly.

Comment: Are you currently using `Go` extension in VS Code?

Comment: I believe so yes, and I using a Mac desktop to run my program. And for the life of me, I don't understand what is causing this issue.

Comment: By default, VSC runs a formatter on save. The default formatter it runs will remove *unused* imports. It is correct to remove unused imports. The fix would be to use the import you've added before saving the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Turns out it was a simple matter of how I was naming the variables in the second file. I was naming the variables how I usually do by underlining the first letter and capitalizing the second. Which works fine in the main executable file, but creates an unreadable error for Golang when you are trying to call it to your main file.

By simply renaming the variables and capitalizing the first letter of the file instead, when you call it to the second file, it seems to work without any more trouble.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out on the matter, because I spent a few hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.